# Convert XML string to URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

This question was asked before but the answer only showed how to do it in PHP.

I have a Javascript library which will only accept a URL to an XML file - however I have the desired XML in a string.

**Can I turn a string of XML into an XML file with a url I can pass to this library which only accepts a link to an XML file?**

I know you can convert a string of XML to an XML object using jQuery's parseXML function but that's not enough - I need an actual URL.

Comment: I'm curious why someone down voted the question? Could you explain?

Comment: Is this JavaScript library a public library? If so, share what the library is, and maybe other users of the library know a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, it's JWPlayer: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer

Comment: Specifically, I'm referring to the tag attribute under the advertising section: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1431665-basic-preroll-video-ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on browser support level, you can possibly convert the XML string into a data URL, like this:

```
var url = 'data:application/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(xmlString);
```

Comment: Hey, there's another issue where the link actually has to be https as well - any idea how to achieve that? Right now I'm getting the error, "XMLHttpRequest cannot load data:application/xml,%3CVAST%20version%3D'2.0.1'%3E%20%20%20%20%3CAd%20id%3…3C%2FInLine%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FAd%3E%20%20%20%20%3C%2FVAST%3E. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'https://zynga2-a.akamaihd.net' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Doesn't sound like this is compatible with data URLs. It's using `XMLHttpRequest` which needs HTTP URLs.

Comment: Ok got it - so is there anyway to get an HTTP url without uploading the file?

Comment: If you only have the XML in the browser, no. HTTP requires an HTTP server, which you cannot create in client JS code.